# I got java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even if I increased the permgen size available to Eclipse. How to fix?

Tags: eclipse, adt, out-of-memory, ubuntu-11.10

I've modified eclipse.ini to fix java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. But the problem still persists. These are the options set inside eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
3000m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=3000m
-Xms3000m
-Xmx3000m
-XX:PermSize=3000m
```

This is the error that I get when I open any file of a generic Android project:

```
Exception in thread "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Note: I'm using Eclipse junco on Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm trying to developing an android app with ADT plugin.

Comment: It seems unlikely that it is actually using nearly 3GB of permgen space - I'm guessing that, for some reason, the VM isn't actually being started with the parameters you are expecting it to, and you don't actually have 3,000 MB of permgen space. Can you attach to the process with VisualVM and verify how much permgen space is actually available? This will help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed: I removed my eclipse "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" and I used "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" instead. Now everything works fine.
Thank you every body for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at your code instead of eclipse. Maybe there's a bug in it which is causing it to allocate too much memory or it is not written very efficient. Possible causes of out an memory exceptions would be:

-Loading large files in to the RAM

-Infinite loops creating objects or appending data to variables

-Storing large amounts of any kind of data in the RAM

I hope this will help you get closer to a solution.

Comment: Code should be ok because it's a sample project of Android SDK (Notepad example). I can build it properly, but If I open any .xml file, I'll get the error. I'm agree with you that the issue seems related to the occupied memory, but I should find a way to fix it because I've got a 3GB of ram: probably I need only to set some variable environment for eclipse or JVM to solve it.